# How to prevent Saint Bernard/GSD mix from going through the window

Tags: windows

Summary: Saint Bernard/GSD mix dog (not quite 2 years old) will bang on the picture window when there is excitement going on outside (birds, rabbits, mailman, etc). Yes, he gets behavior training when I am home. I am concerned he will knock out the window when I am not home (he has already plowed through the neighbors fence chasing something). I blocked it off so he can't get to the window, but my living room is really small so this takes up room. All of my rooms have windows so keeping him locked in a another room isn't a solution and it isn't fair to him. Leaving him outside all the time isn't a solution either as we have a problem with dogs being stolen for the rampant dog fighting games.

Question: I would like to secure a piece of polycarbonate sheet to the inside of the window so he can't pound on the window itself. What is the correct thickness to prevent him from bending the polycarbonate to get to the window? Is there a better way to secure the window?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: My GSD would easily clear a 6ft iron gate without touching it so if you are putting a full height barrier in front of that door then fine - if not he could jump at it...

Comment: A saint bernard I would like solid protection, bars or similar.  Polycarbonate sheet 3/4 to over an inch thick.

Comment: To determine what may be a proper thickness of polycarbonate, as it would be related to flex over a certain distance, we need the dimensions of the window you want to cover.

Comment: The window is 55" in height, 94" in width (including the trim). It is broken up into three panes with the two side panes being sliding doors. The most concerning is when he pushed at the middle pane. My neighbor said it look like the window was bowing out when the dog hit it.

Comment: contrary to belief, glass does have some give to it.

Comment: can't you just put blinds or shades up to remove the impetus for a charge?

Comment: You may also want to check the Pets stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to [48" x 96" 1/4 thick sheet.](https://www.acmeplastics.com/polycarbonate-sheets/polycarbonate-clear-sheet?v=30507&gclid=Cj0KCQjw06-oBhC6ARIsAGuzdw3iPdn56GgA-I0xh5NbcMbcJ6PkH9tAgzue_hQWEPA0Lc687CWQNRcaAtBlEALw_wcB)of polycarbonate.

It should do the job, unless your dog has ridiculous strength.

Predrill and holes before mounting with screws. I like [Teks screws](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Teks-8-x-1-in-Zinc-Plated-Steel-Phillips-Truss-Head-Lath-Screws-170-Pack-21508/100142621?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RBA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_SIMPSEEK&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RBA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_SIMPSEEK-71700000109986253-58700008375337160-92700076237673158&gclid=Cj0KCQjw06-oBhC6ARIsAGuzdw0eKfeor_Qflh_Bc0RMcPgRjBqsB-KcisLOIB0xs95FB-MohXPS9B4aAjSlEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Comment: Thank you for the help!